# Unable to test my Facebook Ads for Branch.io Differed Deep Links

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, branch.io

I am trying to test my Facebook Ad Deeplink which were made by using Branch.io to make a conversion funnel. Clicking the preview ad button sends the ad link to the phone, but the test ad doesn’t work as intended with deep linking.

Also, while trying to test the Deep Links using "App Ads Helper" --> "Test Deep Link" I am not getting any message or deep-link notification to test the link.

Please, help me with the issue. It would be really helpful to know some other alternatives to effectively test Facebook Ads for deep link implementation.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron from Branch here.

1. Can you confirm that your deep link is of the form https://branchster.app.link/frj9pY6PrM?%243p=a_facebook?
2. Can you confirm you are not calling fetchDeferredAppLink from the Facebook SDK?
3. When you paste your link in the [Facebook Share Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), you should not receive any errors.
4. Please confirm you are providing the IDFA/GAID to Branch on all events.
5. Please confirm you are not calling [setDebug()](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#simulate-an-install) or [testmode](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#simulate-an-install) is not enabled.